# PHP exec() not working on linux using phantomjs

Tags: php, linux, phantomjs

I'm new to phantomjs and I don't know how to use it on linux. The same code that is provided below is working fine on windows but don't know what is wrong with it on linux.
First I just wanna tell you that phantomjs text file and PHP file are in the same folder.
Here is my php file:

```
<?php
$response =  exec ('phantomjs get.js', $one, $two);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

Here is `get.js`

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.loadImages = false;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'file.txt';

page.open('http://www.google.com', function () {
page.render('page.png');
var content = page.content;
fs.write(path, content, 'w');
phantom.exit();
});
```

But there is no response on `file.txt` and `var_dump()`. I have a shared hosting plan. Is it due to some permission problems?

Comment: Does `phantomjs get.js` work when run from the command line? Is phantomjs installed on the Linux host?

Comment: @jedifans I don't know how to check it on command line. On phantomjs web there was written no need to install just copy. So I did that.

Comment: @PaulCrovella the same script was working on my windows

Comment: Do you have SSH access to your site folder?

Comment: I have SSH link on cPanel. @Vaviloff

Comment: Try to login via SSH, go to the folder where phantomjs is and do `chmod +x phantomjs`. Then do `phantomjs get.js` and see what it will print. if it doesn't work, add any errors to the question.